# Assigning Text Fields to an Array

Tags: ios5

I am drawing a number of text fields on the screen programmatically. How can I assign them to an Array and reference them?

Answer (score 0):

it really depends on the language, but in php you'd name them with [], so

```
<input type="text" name="arr[]">
```

Answer (score 0):

In the class that you are creating them in, you should first create your array as a property (in your .h file:)

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *textFieldArray;
```

Then, where you create your textField's:

```
self.textFieldArray = [NSMutableArray new];
[self.textFieldArray addObject:textField1];
[self.textFieldArray addObject:textField2];
[self.textFieldArray addObject:textField3];
```

Then, in order to access the text field's stored in the array, you would use (changing the index number as appropriate):

```
UITextField *textField = [self.textFieldArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can use

Instance Methods addObject:
Inserts a given object at the end of the array.

- (void)addObject:(id)anObject